# Reload nginx even when configtest failed

Tags: nginx

I would like to be able to reload nginx even when the configtest fails. Why I want this? Well in my case multiple users are able to modify nginx configs. Initially these configs are syntacticly correct, still I have to keep in mind that the user might not submit a valid config. There are some hooks what reload nginx but there are no hooks on actions such as when a user modifies a nginx config.

Is it possible to reload nginx and ignore all changes in configs what didn't pass the test? So it uses the stable version of that invalid config.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Configtest validates the configuration, and confirms that *can be read and parsed* by NginX. If the test fails, NginX *can't run*.

If you want multiple people able to make configuration changes and prevent invalid configurations from stopping up the webserver, you should have a shared version control repository such as `git` keeping track of the changes people submit.

Post-commit hooks can be used to run the configuration test on the changes, and then deploy *if and only if* the changes are sane.

Comment: I like the whole git approach but, I'm missing the part where you explain. How to confirm that the changes are sane / passed the config test.

Comment: @Fleuv easy. Set a hook to run `nginx -t -c /your/new/nginx.conf`